# ArgumentError: quantiles are undefined in presence of NaNs or missing values

Tags: julia, nan, boxplot, missing-data

I would like to create a boxplot that contains some missing values in Julia. Here is some reproducible code:

```
using DataFrames
using StatsPlots
df = DataFrame(y = [1,2,3,2,1,2,4,NaN,NaN,2,1])

boxplot(df[!, "y"])
```

Output:

```
ArgumentError: quantiles are undefined in presence of NaNs or missing values
```

I know that the error happens because of the `NaN` values, but is there not an option in `boxplot` to still plot the values instead of removing the missing values beforehand? I would assume that it might be designed in a way that it works in presence of missing values. In R it will still plot the boxplot, so I was wondering why in `Julia` you must remove these missing values and what is an appropriate way to do this?

Comment: `boxplot(filter(!isnan, df[!, "y"]))`

Comment: Sometimes an error is like a warning. Why do you have `NaN` values? What should they be? How does this effect the boxplot? Maybe `missing` values are more appropriate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> so I was wondering why in Julia you must remove these missing values

So the general reason is difference in philosophy of design behind R and Julia.
R was designed to be maximally convenient at the risk of doing an incorrect thing sometimes. It tries to guess what you most likely want and does this. In this case - you most likely want `NaN` values to be ignored.

Julia is designed for safety and production use. If you have `NaN` in your data it means that data preparation process had some serious issue (like division of 0 by 0). In production scenarios you want your code to error in such cases as otherwise it is hard to identify the root cause of the issue.

Now, seconding what Dan Getz commented - most likely your `NaN` is actually `missing` (as you refer to it as missing). These two should not be mixed and have a significantly different interpretation. `NaN` is a value that is undefined or unrepresentable, especially in floating-point arithmetic (e.g. 0 divided by 0). While `missing` is a value that is missing (e.g. we have not collected a measurement).

Still - even if your data contained `missing` you would get an error for the same safety reason.

> what is an appropriate way to do this?

`NaN`s are very rare in practice, so what Dan Getz recommended is a typical way to filter them. Other would be `[x for x in df.y if !isnan(x)]`.

If you had `missing` values in your data (as this is most likely what you want) you should write `boxplot(skipmissing(df.y))`.